# how implements websocket in angular 2 and laravel?

Tags: angular, laravel-5, websocket

I'm developing a system with my backend in laravel and my frontend in angular 2. I would like my control panel home page to update in real time.

The question seems generic, I apologize, but I really do not know where to start. I searched the internet, but I did not find anything specifically voted to angular 2 and laravel.

I thought about using the google firebase. So I would have to save whatever I wanted it to be in real time in the mysql database and in the firebase. But I do not know if saving in two places would be the best solution.

Could someone guide me in the best alternative?

Comment: A good start is at their docs. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/broadcasting#introduction
 https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/broadcasting#installing-laravel-echo

Comment: Here is a tutorial on using Laravel on backend with Angular on frontend. For real-time features, you can use the Interval() on your observable, however; a better implementation would be a web-socket. I can find no article on the internet with anything on Laravel + Angular + Websocket. Video Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vu7l574xVao&list=PL55RiY5tL51rrgq6xi67Mc6cwOHXw_nB1